# Symbolic Links wont work

Tags: symbolic-link

I'm trying to move my .vimrc file into my .vim folder.
I read that a symbolic link would allow vim to be able to find my .vimrc file. 
So i go,

```
ln -s ~/.vim/.vimrc ~/.vimrc
```

But all this seems to do is create a empty .vimrc file in my home folder!!

What is going on?

Answer (score 3):

You reversed the symlink for creating a .vimrc in ~/.vim. It should be:

```
ln -s ~/.vimrc ~/.vim/.vimrc
```

Edit: Try using the absolute location. This is for creating a symlink of /home/username/.vim/.vimrc into /home/username/

```
ln -s /home/username/.vim/.vimrc /home/username/.vimrc
```

Comment: Yes but when i do that it gives me an error saying file exists. I moved my vimrc file into .vim already. Now i just want vim to find it when it loads. Is that what symbolic links are for?

Comment: If your vim can't find your .vimrc that is a different issue. You can use a symbolic link to link wherever your current .vimrc is to the proper location.

Comment: vim assumes that your .vimrc file is in the home directory so you could just leave it where it currently is.

Comment: I do have a .vimrc file in my ~/.vim directory. I thought that was the whole point of symbolic links. What i want is for VIM, when it starts up, to look for .vimrc in my home directory, follow the symbolic link, and then read the .vimrc file in my ~/.vim directory. I do not want to keep a copy of it in my home directory. What do i have to do?

Comment: Ah, your initial post said you wanted to move the .vimrc file into the .vim folder. Your initial symlink creates a link from your .vim folder to the home directory. Try using the absolute location. So, `ln -s /home/username/.vim/.vimrc /home/username/.vimrc`

Comment: Using the full path works. Thanks. However it still creates a .vimrc file in my home directory. I didn't know symbolic links were files themselves. So this fix still clutters up my home folder.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6897/discussion-between-fawkes5-and-sheldonk)

Comment: Add your full path comment to an answer and ill give you credit

Answer (score 1):

Symbolic links create a link from one location to another.  The [Wikipedia page on the subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link#POSIX_and_Unix-like_operating_systems) explains it pretty well.  From what you're doing, you're trying to create a link from `~/.vim/.vimrc` to `~/.vimrc`.  What has me curious is that your source file is a really weird directory for that file to be in.  I expect that it doesn't really exist, and that is why you're coming up with an empty file at the target link.

Comment: Whats so weird about the directory ~/.vim?